# Program Not Responding and Finished With An Error Message

Tags: omnet++

I'm making a randomly generated network where the node will send a message randomly to two nodes. The receiving nodes will then forward the message to two other nodes if they haven't know the message before (represented with updated parameter in the ned file). Nodes that already know the message will only delete the message. There's no problem with constructing the network, but running the network make the program not responding with only "Finished with an error" message after close the not responding program.

Here's my code:

Ned file:

```
simple Sg3
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
        bool updated;
    gates:
        input in[];  // declare in[] and out[] to be vector gates
        output out[];
}

network Simplegossip3
{
    parameters:
        int count;
        double connectedness; // 0.0<x<1.0
        @display("bgb=640,444");
        
    submodules:
        node[count]: Sg3 {
            gates:
                in[]; 
                out[];
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..count-2, for j=i+1..count-1, if uniform(0,1)<connectedness {
            node[i].out++ --> node[j].in++;
            node[i].in++ <-- node[j].out++;
        }
}
```

Here's the cc file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;

/**
 * First attempt for gossip protocol
 */
class Sg3 : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;

};
Define_Module(Sg3);

void Sg3::initialize()
{
    bool status = par("updated");
    if (status == true) {
        cMessage *update = new cMessage("1st message");
        int j = gateSize("out");
        int k = intuniform(0, j-1);
        send(update, "out",k);
    }
}

void Sg3::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    bool updatestatus = par("updated");
    int sid = msg->getArrivalGate()->getIndex(); //variable containing the message source
    int n = gateSize("out");

    if (strncmp (msg->getName(),"1st message",2) == 0) {
        if (updatestatus == true){
            delete msg;
        }
        else {
            par("updated").setBoolValue(true);
            delete msg;
            cMessage *update = new cMessage("1st message");
            int l = intuniform(0, n-1);
            do {
                int l = intuniform(0, n-1); //preventing a node asking updated status to the same node it just sent an update to
            }
            while (l == sid);
            send(update, "out", l);

            int m = intuniform(0, n-1);
            do {
                do {
                    int m = intuniform(0, n-1); //choosing other gate to send two message at the same time
                }
                while (m==l);
            }
            while (m == sid);
            send(update, "out", m);
        }
    }
}
```

I failed to find the cause of this problem, I'm sorry for the vague question. I'll really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, inside each do-while loop you have created a new variable (inner). However, then the outer one is compared. The loop should look like:

```
int l = intuniform(0, n-1);
do {
  l = intuniform(0, n-1); // not "int l = ..."
} while (l == sid);
```

The same must be done for the second do-while loop.

Second problem is a logical issue connected with these loops:

```
int m = intuniform(0, n-1);
do {
   do {
     m = intuniform(0, n-1); // not "int m = ..."
   } while (m==l);
} while (m == sid);
```

Let's assume that:

```
**.count = 3
```

Then `n=2`, and `sid` may equal 0 or 1 - let's assume that `sid=1`. After the first do-while loop `l=0`, because it must be different from `sid`. The loops will finish when `m != 0` and `m != 1`. However,  `m` may be equal to 0 or 1, because `intuniform (0,1)` may return only these numbers. As a consequence, these loops are infinitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I'm copying my previous code (where the first problem didn't surfaced) causing me not realizing that its a bad coding. As for the second problem, preventing **.count = 2 to enter the loop seems to solve the problem. 

Thanks for the help.